# Regex needed for optional last digit

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out a regex for a version parser.
I need to parse a version containing a major.minor.patch.build version string with 3 to 4 digits with the last (4th) digit optional.

For example the version could be:
`1.2.3.4`
or
`1.2.3`

I have my regex as the following, but it fails for `1.2.3` version string:

regex = `"(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)?"`

Also, do I need the double back slashes ?

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you want:

```
(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(\.(\d+))?
```

`\d` matches any single number <=> `[0-9]`

`\.` to match the `.` character (a single `.` in a regex matches any single character)

You can prepend '^' and append '$' to the regex to ensure there's no garbage before or after your version.

Answer (score 1):

In your regex you have to make the last part `\.(\d+)` including the dot optional or else it would match `1.2.3.4` but also `1.2.3.`

Try it like this with an optional last group where the dot and the digits are optional:

[`^\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/WZ3ipF/1)

Or with capturing groups and the last is a non capturing group with a dot and a capturing group for the last digits:

[`^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/WZ3ipF/2/)

Instead of using anchors `^` and `$` you could use a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) [`\b`](https://regex101.com/r/saq0Jk/1)

There is no programming language specified concerning the double back slashes but what might help is when you open the regex101 demo link , there is a link under **tools** -> **code generator** where you can select a programming language. Perhaps that could be helpful.